# Xcode M1: Run Designed for iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, ipad, apple-m1

Hello fellow [iOS] Developers!

I've just got my M1 MacBook Pro and been loving how we can test our Apps without even using our mobile devices (props to Apple!!)

So far, I was able to test the app behaviour as it was for iPad (Running "Designed for iPad"), so **I wonder if there's a way to build the app as if it was for an iPhone and run it on the M1?** This would be awesome!

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**Yes, You can.**

One simple smart hack is to

> uncheck iPad from Deployment info
> and then simply run the app you would see that the text would change to

[image]

Detailed Steps:

1. Select Project from Project Navigator
2. Select your specific target > Go to General
3. Under Deployment Info `"Uncheck iPad"`

> Bas ho gya, Khatam, Tata, Bye Bye

**Just run the Project**

Answer (score -1):

The answer is no, you cannot, if you mean native iPhone app on the M1. At least as far as I’ve seen. The simulator will continue to offer you to run the iPhone apps, as you probably have seen already.

As far as I understand, however, iPhone-only apps available on the iPhone are an exception. Whenever an app contains both iPhone and iPad versions of that same app (universal iOS apps), Apple ignores the iPhone version and makes available the iPad version exclusively out of those two iOS/iPadOS apps.

You should watch the video by Apple, ”Introducing iPad apps for Mac”, WWDC 2019, available in the ”Apple Developer” app (you can find it on the App Store). Here’s a web link if you prefer it: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/205/

Here is a quote from the transcript of that video:

> Now along those lines, there's also some apps that are just not
> candidates for this technology.
>
> One example is iPhone apps. iPhone apps are optimized for the smaller screen, so they're trying to take advantage of that small screen. **We really want you to have an iPad app that's taking advantage of larger screen sizes before bringing it to the Mac.**

In 2019, this was all about Mac Catalyst on Intel Macs, but I think it still holds true today on M1: it is all about taking advantage of the similarity between macOS and iPadOS in terms of the screen.

Comment: It is actually possible to run the App on ARM as "Designed for iPhone". I discover that if you change the build target exclusively to iPhone it will do the trick ;) 
Thanks anyway!

Comment: Okay, I see! Good to know. No problem :)